# How to copy/download a cell's raw decimal value

Tags: google-sheets

Copying a decimal value from a cell set to show only N decimal places of that value actually copies to your clipboard what's shown, not the raw value.
The same happens when downloading a sheet as a CSV. Actual cell values are substituted by what's set to show (i.e. limited number of decimal values).

Is there a way to copy/download actual cell values for decimal numbers without having to update the cell's shown decimal places?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user two times.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to create a new sheet where you get the numbers in their raw format, and export the new sheet, like this:

1. Choose **Insert > Sheet**.
2. Put a formula like this in cell `A1` of the new sheet: `=arrayformula(to_pure_number(Sheet1!A1:Z))`
3. Export or copy the new sheet instead of the original.

Another way is to export the values programatically. See [How to export Multiple sheets in (.csv) format in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74654152/13045193). You will have to replace this line:

```
    const values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
```

...with something like this:

```
    const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

Comment: For a single value, copy it from the formula bar instead from the cell.